# "Site Offline" message can't be disabled

Tags: offline

We installed a plugin to show our site offline for a few days during an update. But after finishing the update we cant remove the "Site offline" message. Finally we uninstalled the plugin, but the frontpage still shows "Site offline". Any suggestions om how to get the site "online" again? ( no, plugin developer does not answer our emails..)

Comment: delete the plugin folder via ftp or file manager. Also post your site url.

Comment: Show link to repo.

Comment: Or at least the url to the live site

Comment: No one can really help unless you post a URL.

Comment: We definitely need to know **Exactly what "Maintenance Mode"** Plugin you used, either with a link to the Plugin's listing in the WPORG Plugin Repository, or a link to where you downloaded the Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

**Check for a .maintenance file (if so, delete it) in your wp root** and also check your .htaccess file

Comment: The plugin folder is deleted, but it does not help, and .htaccess seems to be fine

Comment: Again, check for a `.maintenance` file in the root of your wordpress install!!

Comment: and make sure hidden files are showing your FTP client

Comment: no .maintenance file, and I cant find any hidden files. ( I turned on "Force showing hidden files" in Filezilla

Answer (score 0):

I could be that the plugin added some wired thing as DB-option that gets autoloaded. Please check your DB-Options table for unknown keys/values. Then do cross file searches inside the plugins folder for the key.

Comment: I am afraid I dont know what keys/values that are unknown in my installation